# IE 7 Bug? Setting the height of an <li> resets an ordered list's counter

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I've hit what I can only assume is an IE7 bug but I haven't been able to find mention of it anywhere online. It seems that setting the height of `<li>` elements in an ordered list resets the list's counter (similar to the `counter-reset` css property).

It's quite easy to reproduce, rendering the following code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        li { height: 20px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <ol>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
    </ol>

</body>
</html>
```

Produces this...

[image: Rendered by IE9 using Browser mode: IE7, Document Mode: IE7 standards]

Removing the CSS rule fixes the problem.

Why oh why is this happening and how can I stop it? I'd also be interested in any existing discussions or documentation of this problem. I can't be the first to encounter it.

Note: I don't currently have access to a true IE7 machine so I've been using the IE7 browser mode in IE9. I imagine it's accurate?

Comment: that is strange, I have a native IE7 box, let me check that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I can confirm that this is indeed a bug in IE7 and below.

Setting a `height` or a `width` will do it.

A simple fix is:

```
ol li {
  display:list-item;
  height:40px;
}
```

Someone has encountered this before and there are a number of workarounds.

http://weblogs.asp.net/marksmith/archive/2008/01/11/ie7-bug.aspx